# Does Solana support any popular zkSNARK libraries?

Tags: solana-program, rust, development, zkp

I am learning how to compile zkSNARK circuits with Iden3's circom compiler.
https://iden3.io/
https://github.com/iden3/circom

I am seeing pretty good usage of circom, Polygon is using it, and other projects like 0xParc use it to teach zkSNARK.
I am using semaphore's circom circuits (https://semaphore.appliedzkp.org/)
I am compiling them, and there are options to :

1. compile to wasm to run off chain
2. solidity, to run on ethereum chain
   I really like how Solana has an option to use Rust for crypto contracts, so I am interested.

Does Solana have any zkSNARK libraries like Iden3 + Circom?
Does it have any sovereign identity projects using those zkSNARK libraries like semaphore?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solana doesn't natively support any zk-SNARK libraries, although there are ad-hoc implementations depending on the use case.
https://github.com/Lightprotocol/light-protocol-program

The reason being that zk-proofs are very compute intensive. There are some curve-25519 syscalls that would be made available soon which you can use to build simple pairing based zkSNARKs

https://docs.rs/solana-zk-token-sdk/latest/solana_zk_token_sdk/index.html

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/28216